# disabled ng-repeat with button using angularjs when i am reloading disabled not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have list of stores which is shown based services with one accept button once user clicked that apply button disabled but when i am reloading that page
disabled is not working.
expectation:Once user clicked Apply Button button should be disabled when ever user goes to that page button should be disabled.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.services = [
    {_id: 1, title: "Service 1"},
    {_id: 2, title: "Service 2"},
    {_id: 3, title: "Service 3"}
  ];
  
  $scope.apply = function(service){
    console.log(service._id + " clicked");
    service.clicked = true;
  }
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.17/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.17"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    
    <div class="list card" data-ng-repeat="service in services">
      <i> {{service.title}} </i>
     <button ng-click="apply(service)" ng-disabled="service.clicked">apply</button>
  
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your clicked variable in only set in your current session. When you reload the page it is lost and goes back to the default value. You need to persist that data for each service in your list so that it is remembered when the user reloads the page. You could use an API to request the services. Then when you click accept make another AJAX request marking that service as accepted etc. So when the user reloads the page they get the updated info. There's other options like Local/SessionStorage to persist the data, or indexedDB. But that is client side storage.

Comment: how can i use local Storage for this please can you explain me

Comment: Ill throw together a fiddle one moment...

Comment: can u please share the plunkar

Comment: see my answer i can explain better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to save to localStorage. This will persist when the tab/window is closed. However it is client storage. If the user opens it in a new browser it won't have that data. If the data needs to persist across machines then a back-end database is probably a better option.

localStorage and sessionStorage store the object as key value pairs. Where the value is converted to a string. You will have to decide on the best structure for your needs.

I decided on a single key storing everything as JSON. This means on every read i have to parse it. To save it means i have to read everything, modify the item i need then save it all back.

The other alternative is indexedDB, it is a client side database. Allows for complex data structures, and doesn't require you to stringify your objects first, however it is more complex to implement and isn't as well supported as localStorage.

here's a very rough quick idea of localStorage: http://jsfiddle.net/15xw00ar/

Here's the nuts n bolts of the service:

```
app.service('ServiceHelper', function(){    
    //Our service helper service

    this.get = function(){
        //Read service from local storage, remember its saved as a string so parse
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('services'));
    }

    this.save = function (title) {
        //Save a new service. First have to read all, append new service then save all
        var services = this.get('services') || [];

        services.push({title: title, accepted: false});

        localStorage.setItem('services', JSON.stringify(services));
    }

    this.markedAsAccepted = function (i){
        //Mark service as accepted at a certain index
        var services = this.get();

        services[i].accepted = true;

        localStorage.setItem('services', JSON.stringify(services));
    }
});
```

some docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2):

I believe you should go for an SPA kind of thing using [**ngRoute module**](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07) & that will have different view based on their url.

Instead of storing variables inside controller you should create a service and that would be having sharable variable. As you goes to other page in your application the relying controller will destroy its scope as soon as the other template with controller gets loaded to the page.

**Service**

```
app.service('dataService', function(){
   this.services  = [
    {_id: 1, title: "Service 1"},
    {_id: 2, title: "Service 2"},
    {_id: 3, title: "Service 3"}
  ];

})
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, dataService) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  $scope.services = dataService.services;

  $scope.apply = function(service){
    console.log(service._id + " clicked");
    service.clicked = true;
  }

});
```